# jquery-1.8.1 Invalid argument in IE7 - getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm having trouble narrowing this one down.
In IE8 and above works fine.
I don't even know how to debug this, since IE7 doesn't have developer tools.

The error says line 6256 (first in the snippet bellow); char 6 (letter 'i' of 'if'); code 0:

```
if ( typeof elem.getElementsByTagName !== "undefined" ) { /***this is the line that throws Invalid Argument***/
    // handleScript alters the DOM, so use jQuery.merge to ensure snapshot iteration
    jsTags = jQuery.grep( jQuery.merge( [], elem.getElementsByTagName("script") ), handleScript );

    // Splice the scripts into ret after their former ancestor and advance our index beyond them
    ret.splice.apply( ret, [i + 1, 0].concat( jsTags ) );
    i += jsTags.length;
}
```

The code is part of function *clean*.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

**EDIT I:**
When I open debugger in IE9, put breakpoint on that line and then open stack trace this is what I see:

[image]

So I assume that it's triggered by $(document).ready

**EDIT II**
It seems that jsfiddle is currently down so I'm posting the code here and creating jsbin snippet:

http://jsbin.com/avajuw/1/edit

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation-block" style="width: 154px; height: 100%;">
  <ul id="sliding-navigation">
    <li class="sliding-element">
         <h4>Docs</h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // the actual code I run is in comments
  // var baseRestUrl = top.location.protocol + '//' + top.location.host + top.location.pathname + 'jaxrs';
  var baseRestUrl = 'http//host:port/archive/jaxrs';
  var linksRestUrl = baseRestUrl + '/links';
  var fileRestUrl = baseRestUrl + '/file';
  // var params = top.location.search;
  var params = 'pnd=231352122&pgv=654321321321';

  // $.getJSON(linksUrl, function(json) {   //to get something like:
  var json = {
    "links": {
        "lista": [{
            "clipExt": "pnd",
            "docId": "1203200110003774",
            "imageDesc": "Front b/w",
            "imageName": "Img_f_bw"
        }, {
            "clipExt": "pgv",
            "docId": "1203200110003774",
            "imageDesc": "Front gray",
            "imageName": "Img_f_gr"
        }]
      }
  };

  //var lista = (!json.links.lista[1]) ? json.links : json.links.lista;
  //alert(lista);

  $.each(json.links.lista, function(i, item) {
    var clipExt = item.clipExt;

    var fileLink = fileRestUrl + '?' +
        'un=' + item.docId + '&' +
        'ext=' + clipExt + '&' + clipExt + '=' + extractParam(params, clipExt);

    $('#sliding-navigation').append(
        "<li class=\"sliding-element\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"fetchImage('" + fileLink + "', this)\">" + item.imageDesc + "</a></li>");

  });
});

function extractParam(url, paramName) {
    var tmp = (url.match(RegExp("[?|&]" + paramName + '=(.+?)(&|$)')) || [null])[1];
    return tmp;    
}
```

Comment: why even check! You are using jQuery so use the library. lol  `jQuery $(elem).find("script").get()`

Comment: Have you tried using IE7's emulation mode in IE8 so you can at least debug it? (The emulation is not perfect but working in the vast majority of cases)

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean by that. I'm JS noob.

Comment: @RogerC thanks for that. In IE9, when I switch to browser and document mode to IE7 everything works just fine.

Comment: Please post your code that is interacting with jquery when this error occurs.

Comment: @epascarello The above code is within jquery.js

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the snippet above is from jquery-1.8.1.js

Comment: epascarelo means jquery provides abstraction so you don't have to `typeof elem.getElementsByTagName` or other kind of ways to access the dom that are not cross browser compliant; use the library !

Comment: @KevinB I added the image in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @mbonaci yes, that shows what method in jquery.js is throwing the error. What in your code is using jquery.js when that error happens?

Comment: Post the code around where you are using .append

Comment: @KevinB I haven't responded immediately because I went home from work. I'll check the code and post back the findings first thing Monday morning.

Comment: @KevinB response posted bellow the answer. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the given "error" is missleading :) sometimes if you give some "not existing elements" to jquery, where it hopes to have some element, it just does nonsense ... please try to locate the problem somewhere in your written code: do you have any function calls that you registered for (document).ready() ? Is every dom-node a real dom-node and not null/undefined?

Comment: I haven't responded immediately because I went home from work. I'll check the code and post back the findings first thing Monday morning. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the code (normally working in FF17, IE8 and IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/Yv4q7/9/

Answer (score 1):

This html works in IE9 when IE7 mode is turned ON, while your example at jafiddle breaks in the same mode. It's same code you posted, but put in the local file. So problem must be elsewhere.

Create html file with this markup (same as your example) and open in your IE7. Does it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation-block" style="width: 154px; height: 100%;">
    <ul id="sliding-navigation">
        <li class="sliding-element">
             <h4>Dokumenti</h4>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // the actual code I run is in comments
    // var baseRestUrl = top.location.protocol + '//' + top.location.host + top.location.pathname + 'jaxrs';
    var baseRestUrl = 'http//host:port/archive/jaxrs';
    var linksRestUrl = baseRestUrl + '/links';
    var fileRestUrl = baseRestUrl + '/file';
    // var params = top.location.search;
    var params = 'pnd=231352122&pgv=654321321321';

    // $.getJSON(linksUrl, function(json) {   //to get something like:
    var json = {
        "links": {
            "lista": [{
                "clipExt": "pnd",
                "docId": "1203200110003774",
                "imageDesc": "Front b/w",
                "imageName": "Img_f_bw"
            }, {
                "clipExt": "pgv",
                "docId": "1203200110003774",
                "imageDesc": "Front gray",
                "imageName": "Img_f_gr"
            }]
        }
    };

    //var lista = (!json.links.lista[1]) ? json.links : json.links.lista;
    //alert(lista);

    $.each(json.links.lista, function(i, item) {
        var clipExt = item.clipExt;

        var fileLink = fileRestUrl + '?' +
            'un=' + item.docId + '&' +
            'ext=' + clipExt + '&' + clipExt + '=' + extractParam(params, clipExt);

        $('#sliding-navigation').append(
            "<li class=\"sliding-element\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"fetchImage('" + fileLink + "', this)\">" + item.imageDesc + "</a></li>");

    });
});

function extractParam(url, paramName) {
    var tmp = (url.match(RegExp("[?|&]" + paramName + '=(.+?)(&|$)')) || [null])[1];
    return tmp;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in IE9 with IE7 mode ON for me too, but not in IE7. Ok, good idea, I'll run it locally and report back the findings in 8 hrs or so. Thanks

Comment: This answer has not provided the solution, but I also came to the conclusion that the cause is not within this part of the code (so really, there was never any chance the answer will provide the exact solution). Since I'm currently working on a different location and don't have access to the code I'm awarding points like this.